# OpenGL: issues with converting floats from texture to integers in fragment shader

Tags: opengl

- I render to a texture which is in the format `GL_RGBA8`.
- When I render to this texture I have a fragment shader whose output is set to `color = (1/255, 0, 0, 1)`. Triangles are overlapping each other and I set the blend mode to `(GL_ONE, GL_ONE)` so for example if 2 triangles overlap for a given fragment, the resulting pixel at that fragment position will have value (2/255.0).
- I then use this texture in a second pass (applied to a quad filling up the screen). My goal at this point when I read the values back from the texture is to convert the values (which are in floating point format in the range [0:1]) back to integers in the range [0:255]. If I look at the pixel that add value (2.0/255.0) I should have the result `(2.0/255.0) * 255.0 = 2.0` but I don't.

If I do

```
float a = (texture(colorTexture, texCoord).x * 255);
float b = (a == 2) ? 1.0 : 0;
color = vec4(0, b, 0, 1);
```

I get a black image. If I do

```
float a = (texture(colorTexture, texCoord).x * 255);
float b = (a > 1.999 && a <= 2) ? 1.0 : 0;
color = vec4(0, b, 0, 1);
```

I get the expected result. So in summary it seems like the convention back to [0:255] suffers from floating precision issues.

```
precision highp float;
```

Doesn't make a difference. I also turned filtering off (and no mipmaps).

This would work:

```
float a = ceil(texture(colorTexture, texCoord).x * 255);
```

Though in general that doesn't like very robust as a solution (why would ceil work and not floor for example, why is the value 1.999999 rather than 2.00001 and can I be sure it will always be that way?). People must have done that before so I am sure there's a much better way to guaranteeing you get an accurate result without doing too much fiddling with the numbers. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

## EDIT

As pointed in 2 comments, it's right from the way floating point numbers are encoded that you can't get a guarantee that you will get a "integer" number back even if the number is even (that's good to be reminded of this important point). So I reformulate my question which is then, is there a preferred way in GLSL to clamp number to its closest integer values?

And that would be `round`:

```
float a = round(texture(colorTexture, texCoord).x * 255);
```

Hope this can help other people in the future though.

Comment: `1/3 * 3 != 1` Similarly, you are hopping `texture...x * 255` to be an exact number. If you can work with integers these issues are gone.

Comment: @Ripi2 - that's a good comment ))) but my example is an even number. And still what would be the best method then. Is there something like `clamp to nearest int` method?

Comment: @user18490: "*People must have done that before*" Why? I cannot think of one reason why I would ever need to do that. If you need to work with integers, write to an integer texture.

Comment: @user18490: "*my example is an even number*" I'm not sure why you think that matters.

Comment: @NicoBolas: you are right from a computer standpoint it doesn't. It gives you no guarantee that the result will be back to 2. So I will reformulate my question. What's the best method to clamp to nearest integer)

Comment: GLSL **round(x)** function returns a value equal to the nearest integer to x